# How to load savedsearch with huge data in MR script? NetSuite

Tags: mapreduce, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

We have a transactional saved search with lines in millions. The saved search fails to get load in UI, is there any way to load such saved searches in the map-reduce script?

I tried using pagination but it still shows an error (ABORT_SEARCH_EXCEEDED_MAX_TIME).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netsuite may stil time out depending on the complexity of the search but you do not have to run the search in order to send the results to the map stage

```js
function getInputData(ctx){
    return search.load({id:'mysearchid'});
}

function map(ctx){
   var ref = JSON.parse(ctx.value);
   
   const tranRec = record.load({type:ref.recordType, id:ref.id});

   log.debug({
      title:'map stage with '+ ref.values.tranid, //presumes Document Number was a result column
      details: ctx.value // have a look at the serialized form
   });
}
```

Comment: thanks alot for yor answer @bknights but when i pass my search object directly, i do not get some of my SUM fields. Therefore i m applying getResults function in my getInputData

Comment: See my answer to your other question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting all rows, perhaps it's even a better option to get the first nth rows (100K or even less) per MR execution, save the last internal id from the processed row and use the next internal id in the next MR script execution.

Comment: That's a good idea.
but does the MR script process the Search results in sequence?

Comment: No it does not. The execution can be divided into separate processes. 

See also https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4387799161.html